# Problems with linking C++ code

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, linker, static-libraries, linker-errors

I'm tying to learn how to make and use a static library and I've faced some problems. This is what I've done.

First I've written some code and placed in into `String.h` and `String.cpp` files.

Then I've compiled it into an object file:

`mingw32-g++ -c -O2 -s -DNDEBUG String.cpp -o .\obj\String.o`

Then I've archived(?) it:

`ar cr .\lib\String.lib .\obj\String.o`

And indexed(?) it:

`ranlib  .\lib\String.lib`

After that I've successfully compiled and linked the tests with mingw:

`mingw32-g++ -std=c++03 -Wall -O2 -s -DNDEBUG .\test\src\test.cpp .\lib\String.lib -o .\test\bin\test.exe`

The test compiled, linked and ran perfectly.

After that I wanted to include this library into my MSVS12 project. I've:

1. Added a path to the `String.h` to the `Project - C/C++ -General - Additional Include Directories`
2. Included `String.h` to some project header
3. Added a path to the `String.lib` to the `Project - Linker - General - Additional library directories`
4. Added `String.lib` to the `Project - Linker - Input - Additional dependencies`

After all these steps when I try to build the project the linker gives me many `LNK2011` and `LNK2019` errors. It seems to me that it can not find the implementation of my functions...

Please, tell me what I'm doing wrong and how can I fix it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C++ doesn't have much of a standard regarding binary formats -- not even how names are recorded in a library.  (C++ compilers like to "mangle" names, inserting things like argument- and return-type codes into them.  But they don't agree on exactly *how* to do that.)  Result being, libraries from one compiler are rarely portable to another compiler unless the functions in them are declared as `extern "C"`.

You'll have to either declare your library functions as such, or compile the library with Visual Studio if that's where you want to use it.  (You could also put the library's code in a header file if you wanted, but it sounds like you're trying to have an already-compiled, static library.)

Comment: Thank you for an answer! I want to make a universal cross-platform library. And a `String` is just it's part. I provide each module with a makefile and tests. So that anybody can build it on it's machine. So if I want to use it with MSVS I need to run my makefile using some microsoft tools like NMAKE?

Comment: @Kolyunya: A universal, cross-platform, *compiled* library is kinda a pipe dream, for reasons already mentioned.  Binary compatibility sucks between compilers unless you use `extern "C"`, and even then there are a few different formats of libraries. So yeah, someone would generally have to compile it on their machine.  (Or, you could provide a binary for their compiler.  But eh.)

Comment: I mean that the library is opensource. I want to provide sources and makefiles so that anybody could compile it on their machines. Am I doing it correctly? Thank you!

Comment: Do I get it right that a need to use `nmake` now to compile my lib to use with MSVS?

Comment: For those who don't know how to compile C++ code from the console on Windows, use `nmake.exe` for reading makefiles, `cl.exe` as a compiler and `lib.exe` as an archiver. All those are located in `VisualStudio/VC/bin` folder.